Flutter web app - Stripe purchase fully on server side as edge function?
I am building a Flutter web app that includes a purchase option, and I've been looking at using Stripe as the payment gateway.
The problem is that the available Flutter Stripe packages don't support Flutter web (or at least the support is 'experimental'), and also to protect the client secret key these solutions seem to require the use of edge functions.
In that regard,  I have been thinking about the possibility of moving the whole Stripe purchase transaction into an edge function.  This would be for a 'once off payment'. Something like...

A standard Flutter form to capture credit card details
The Flutter web app calls an async edge function that receives the credit card
details as input
The edge function handles all interactions with the Stripe API
The edge function returns back to the Flutter web app the outcome (success/fail) with some form of transaction id.

Is this feasible?
Given that Stripe returns call outcomes as web hooks, how can I build an edge function that waits for a Stripe web hook call to arrive?
